# How to point NGINX to internal npm app with port

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, ssl

I try to put up the Uppy Standalone Companion on a Scaleway instance. I managed to install Uppy and mananged to install Nginx with SSL but now I want the (sub)domain to load the Uppy Companion instead of the standard Nginx homepage.

I tried

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3020;
}
```

When I start companion it shows its running on 0.0.0.0:3020 so I also tried

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3020;
}
```

However, I won't get it to work. Below I've added my Nginx configuration file

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name  companion.mywebsite.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3020;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/companion.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/companion.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }



    server {
    if ($host = companion.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  companion.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}
```

Comment: I'm getting the Nginx Error: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, I feel so stupid now. 
It was a permission error. Fixed by this command:
`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`